# Can Duktape use javascript websocket libraries or any form of socket libraries?

Tags: duktape

I am trying to use duktape as an embedded JS engine, however I can't seem to use Websockets which work typically in browser based JS engine. Does duktape have support for this or any other network protocol within javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Duktape only provides the core Ecmascript engine which doesn't include any I/O, timers, etc.

Comment: So no network protocols at all? If not, has anyone else attempted to use this with duktape?

Comment: Typically one picks an existing library and then writes Ecmascript bindings to it using the Duktape C API, similarly to how browsers have a core Ecmascript engine and the browser then provides setTimeout(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Sami wrote there is no I/O, network or even file system support in duktape as this depends heavily on the target system. However, there is a library called [dukluv](https://github.com/creationix/dukluv) which provides a duktape interface for [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) (the I/O, network, timer etc. library behind Node.js).